# Binding button text to variable in Carouselview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am fairly new to Xamarin and I am trying to bind text data to a button that I want to exist in a carousel view. I can't get the button to show or show the text. When the button is outside of the carousel view the binding works, as I can use x:Name. My research told me that I cannot use x:Name in a carousel as it is expecting controls to change.

The button shows the date and as you swipe left or right, the date will change accordingly, I can change the date with the swipes, I just can't see anything.

```
            <forms:CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView" Grid.Row="1" >
                <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Text="{Binding buttonDate}" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </forms:CarouselView>
```

The codebehind is as follows.

```
public MyPage()
{           
   InitializeComponent();

   this.BindingContext = this;
   var buttonDate = new DateButton
   {
       ButtonDate = DateTime.Now.ToString()
   };
}

public class DateButton
{
    public string ButtonDate { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Item {
  DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<Item>();

data.Add(new Item { Date = DateTime.Now };
data.Add(new Item { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
data.Add(new Item { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) };

MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = data;
```

Because your ItemsSource is a `List<Item>`, the binding context of the DataTemplate will be whichever `Item` is currently "active", so the `Binding Path` should be a `Property` on `Item`.

```
<Button Text="{Binding Date}" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
```